# Passing selector via IBInspectable in Swift 3

Tags: swift, custom-controls, ibinspectable

I created a custom control and I want to pass the action in an @IBInspectable property to achieve the same effect of setting up an @IBAction using UIButton. How should I go about doing this?

```
class MyControl: UIButton {
  // Problem with this string approach is 
  //I have no way to know which instance to perform the selector on.
  @IBInspectable var tapAction: String?  

  // set up tap gesture
  ...

  func labelPressed(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let tapAction = tapAction {
      // How should I convert the string in tapAction into a selector here? 
      //I also want to pass an argument to this selector.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just curious how is `tapAction` variable being set ? I mean what would cause `tapAction` value to change ?

Comment: It's being set in Interface Builder.

Comment: Use a switch case to set the appropriate selector based on a set of string values. In my personal view you could do this a lot easier programatically instead of using `IBInspectable` variable.

Comment: @user1046037 Yes looks like there is no simple way to achieve the same thing that you can achieve with UIButton in IB (where you can specify the touch up inside action handler)

Comment: Do you want to add a tap gesture recogniser which would be called when a user taps on it ?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why do you want it, but... Here is my solution:

Create a `MyActions` class, with actions that `MyControl` can to call:

```
class MyActions: NSObject {
    func foo() {
        print("foo")
    }

    func bar() {
        print("bar")
    }

    func baz() {
        print("baz")
    }
}
```

Replace your `MyControl` class to

```
class MyControl: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var actionClass: String?
    @IBInspectable var tapAction: String?
    private var actions: NSObject?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // initialize actions class
        let bundleName = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!.components(separatedBy: ".").last!
        let className = "\(bundleName).\(actionClass!)"

        guard let targetClass = NSClassFromString(className) as? NSObject.Type else {
            print("Class \(className) not found!")
            return
        }

        self.actions = targetClass.init()

        // create tap gesture
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pressed(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func pressed(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        actions!.perform(Selector(tapAction!))
    }
}
```

And, set attributes of your button:

[image]

You can change the Tap Action in run time, for example:

```
@IBAction func buttonChangeAction(_ sender: Any) {

    buttonMyControl.tapAction = textField.text!
}
```

Maybe you can change my code to pass parameters, but... it's you want?